# Return all products under a category in Laravel web api

Tags: php, laravel, migration

I'm using Laravel 8 web api and how can to obtain all the elements or data that belong to the same parent id, that is, I send the category id 3 through the API,

it must return all the products or elements under this id. How can I relate the tables to have that data? and what would be the method or function that should be in the Show($id) function?

I have some code, but it is not working correctly

Here's my code:
Document Type Controller:

```php
    public function show($id) {
        $userWithDoc = User::where('users.document_type_id','=',$id)
                        ->join('document_types', function($join) use($id){
                            $join->on('document_types.id', '=', 'users.document_type_id');
                            })->get();

        return response()->json($userWithDoc);
    }
```

Model:

```php
    class DocumentType extends Model
     {
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = ['DocumentTypeName'];

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\User');
    }
}
```

Document Type Migration File:

```php
    Schema::create('document_types', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('DocumentTypeName');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

User Migration File:

```php
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('firstName');
            $table->string('middleName')->nullable();
            $table->string('lastName');
            $table->string('userName');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
            
            $table->bigInteger('document_type_id')->unsigned()->default(1);
            $table->foreign('document_type_id')
                  ->references('id')
                  ->on('document_types')
                  ->onUpdate('cascade')
                  ->onDelete('cascade');
      }
```

Comment: Why join at all? Just use Eloquent. `DocumentType::find(3)->with("users")->get();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the join has been over complicated in the `show`?

Try with:

```
public function show($id) {
    $userWithDoc = User::where('users.document_type_id', '=', $id)
         ->join('document_types', 'document_types.id', '=', 'users.document_type_id')
         ->get();

    return response()->json($userWithDoc);
}
```